# MOSS 2007 - Report Service Issue

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

All the reports in the Report Service fails, and I've located an issue with the Tfs_Analysis database.

Trying to process the database, it fails. There are some Dimensions which seems to be related to the problem. Processing the Dimension Test Case results in the following error.

[image]

How may I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Deleted both the tfs_warehouse and tfs_analysis databases
2. Re-created them from TFS Administration Console
3. Rebuild the database

That solved the issue.